# Set Sheet BackgroundColor Same As System BackgroundColor in macOS SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-sheet

Sheet background color looks perfectly fine(sheet background color sets system background color automatically)
**Untill presented view has `.white` background color, then sheet background color becomes white instead of default background color.**
*(sheet background color becomes same as presented view's bgcolor { which is `white` } and one can't differentiate between sheet and presented view bgcolor)*

[Screenshot For customTextView(backColor: .yellow.opacity(0.5))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59ToP.png) { Observe Sheet BGColor }

[Screenshot For customTextView(backColor: .white)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQcO6.png) { Sheet BGColor beomes `white` }

[Screenshot For Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9tAX.png)

This is Sheet Code

```
struct customTextView: View {
    @State var backColor: Color
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is SHEET !")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding()
            .background(backColor)
    }
}
```

How i present that sheet is shown below in code

```
.sheet(isPresented: $open, content: {
    customTextView(backColor: .white)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Below is the way to set sheet background color as system background
> color when presented view has `.white` background color.

**Before macOS 13.3**

```
.sheet(isPresented: $open, content: {
    customTextView(backColor: .white)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        // Below line does the work and sets the system bgcolor as sheet bgcolor
        .background(Color(NSColor.windowBackgroundColor))
})
```

**For macOS 13.3+**

```
.sheet(isPresented: $open, content: {
    customTextView(backColor: .white)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        // Below line does the work and sets the system bgcolor as sheet bgcolor
        .presentationBackground(Color(NSColor.windowBackgroundColor))
})
```